# Update MySql Query for user profile update using php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to update user profile by overwriting current data in the MySql.
It isn't working properly its stating it echos my "the name doesn't exist"

Here is my php code:

``````

```
<?php
// see if the form has been completed
session_start();
include_once("php_includes/check_login_status.php");
include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");
// Initialize any variables that the page might echo
$u = "";
$firstname = "";
$surname = "";
$gender = "Male";
$country = "";
$weight = "";
$height = "";
$password = "";
$password2 = "";

if(isset($_GET["u"])){
    $u = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_GET['u']);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$u' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
$user_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);

// check if the user exists in the database
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($user_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $firstname = $row["firstname"];
    $surname = $row["surname"];
    $weight = $row["weight"];
    $height = $row["height"];
    $email = $row["email"];
    $gender = $row ["gender"];
    }
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $weight = $_POST['weight'];
    $height = $_POST['height'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
mysql_connect ("localhost","root","pass123");   mysql_select_db('worldoi5_social');
    // check if that user exist 
    $exists = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$u' ") or die ("query cant connect");   
    if (mysql_num_rows ($exists) != 0) {
    // update the description in the database       
        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET firstname='$firstname', surname='$surname', weight='$weight', height='$height' WHERE username='$u'") or die ("update could not be applied");
        echo "successful";
} else echo "the name does not exist";  
}
?>
```

I have made the code work with less code, but since i have added more it stopped working, and the data reads fine, I do not see the errors or mistake.

here is a bit of the HTML aswell:

```
        <form action="user1.php" method="POST">
            <div>
            <p>First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="<?=$firstname?>"></p>
            <p>Surname: <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" value="<?=$surname?>"></p>   
            <p>Weight: <input type="text" name="weight" id="weight" value="<?=$weight?>"></p>
            <p>Height: <input type="text" name="height" id="height" value="<?=$height?>"></p>
            <p> <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Update Description"></p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: Right off the bat, mixing `mysqli_*` with `mysql_*` - Do the math `$mysqli_*` + `mysql_*` = **NO GO.**

Comment: What I used to do is echo the contents of mysql_query and then copy+paste it into a MySQL client. 75% percent of the time, just seeing the raw query allows you to notice something wrong.

Comment: Plus, I honestly don't know why you're using `session_start();` for this. Nothing's assigned to one.

Comment: @Fred-ii I am new i don't know much different between them and I can't see `session_start();` being the problem

Comment: how do you echo the actually mysql query @evilpenguin

Comment: I figured it out the problem is that I mixed up the single and double quotes

Comment: I never said that `session_start();` was a "problem", I said => *"Plus, I honestly don't know why you're using session_start(); for this. Nothing's assigned to one."* @user3311898

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii- I removed it as i never used it, I only put it there as i was going to use it later to make this update form more advanced

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer:

from the php code line

`$exists = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$u' ")`

the single and double quots where messed up so i had to use it like this;

`$exists = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname='" . $firstname . "'")`

then it read it properly also i decided to use firstname as the selective